# Is there an open source tool to planarize graphs?

Tags: qgis, open-source-gis, network

I read about the planarize function in ArcGIS, which seem to do exactly what I want. Is there a similar feature in QGIS or another free tool?

I have a shapefile with various shapes intersecting each other and I want each intersection to become a node and between every two nodes to have a simple line.

The goal is to easily convert my .shp in .osm and use it with Graphserver. As it is, Graphserver says I don't have edges, and I deduced the above is my problem.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 7):

In GRASS GIS which is topological you can use [v.net](http://grass.osgeo.org/grass70/manuals/html70_user/v.net.html) for this operation. You can access it through the QGIS-GRASS Toolbox.

Comment: Hi! I had a look about the v.net documentation, I'm not sure about the end result I should get to be able to import this in the graphserver…

Comment: You can then export to a OGR supported format with v.out.ogr.

Comment: Odd the documentation isn't very explicit that it handles intersections.  Did you try this and does it work?

Comment: Not sure this works - see my other answer

Answer (score 4):

In GRASS GIS the [v.clean](http://Returning%20to%20this%20question%203%20years%20on%20...%20Although%20v.net%20will%20break%20intersections%20which%20is%20essential%20for%20net%20building,%20ArcGIS%20planarize%20does%20considerably%20more%20which%20v.net%20doesn't.%20For%20example,%20planarize%20will%20snap%20together%20all%20features%20within%20a%20threshold%20distance%20by%20altering%20their%20shape,%20then%20remove%20any%20duplicates%20thus%20formed.%20This%20is%20great%20for%20cleaning%20up%20bad%20data.%20I%20still%20haven't%20seen%20any%20QGIS%20equivalent%20for%20it.) tool can be set to `break` intersections.  The `rmsa` and `rmdupl` options to v.clean are useful as well.

Returning to this question  for a third time: the `snap` option to `v.clean` will snap together features by altering their shape to fix apparent intersections, etc.  `snap` followed by `break` should thus do a job similar to ArcGIS Planarize.