# QGIS function like ArcGIS Planarize

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, qgis-3

I have a city road network. I have to divide sections that are separated by intersections into one level. With ArcGIS this is done with [Planarize](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/manage-data/editing-existing-features/splitting-lines-at-intersections-with-planarize.htm). I tried split commands, but it applies to all sections of the net. How can I do this by plotting specific sections?

Answer (score 1):

Check out this answer from several years ago - you will need to use the GRASS toolset, but using v.clean correctly should still give you the result you require.

[Is there an open source tool to planarize graphs?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/15371/is-there-an-open-source-tool-to-planarize-graphs)